# Issue with script to delete the files with particular extension

Tags: python, automation

I have written the following script to delete the files with a particular extension.However, this script delete the file with the extension `'.log' or '.txt' or '.css'`.

What if the file extension is `'.log000123'` or `'.log1234'`, so here extension is constant but random numbers are added after the extension. What can be done to delete such files as well through this script?

Any modification in the script or link to any website where such example is covered will be appreciated.

```
import os, time, sys

folder_path = "C:\SampleFolder"
file_ends_with = ".log"
how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove = 7

now = time.time()
only_files = []

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_full_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_full_path) and file.endswith(file_ends_with):
        #Delete files older than x days
        if os.stat(file_full_path).st_mtime < now - how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove * 86400: 
             os.remove(file_full_path)
             print "\n File Removed : " , file_full_path
```

Comment: Have you tried to with `file_ends_with = ".log*"`?

Comment: Yes, Yamila I did, but it did not work.

Comment: Try this: `file[-4:] == file_ends_with`

Comment: You can check `os.path.splitext(name)[1][:4] == '.log':` to check the first four characters of a file's extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os, time, sys

folder_path = "C:\SampleFolder"
file_contains = ".log"
how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove = 7

now = time.time()
only_files = []

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_full_path = os.path.join(folder_path,file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_full_path) and file_contains in file_full_path:
        #Delete files older than x days
        if os.stat(file_full_path).st_mtime < now - how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove * 86400: 
             os.remove(file_full_path)
             print "\n File Removed : " , file_full_path
```

Comment: No, I made one change: the first `if` in you code now checks if `".log"` is in the `file_full_path`. Please read carefully.

Comment: Yes Yamila, it worked like a charm, thank you so much, I really appreciate your help, cheers :)

Comment: Thank you @Shantanu. You can upvote the answer and accept it as the correct one then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions and `os.path.splitext`:

```
import os
import re

file = "myfile.log123"

pattern = ".log(.*)"  # match .log followed by anything
fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)

# check this condition:
if re.match(pattern, ext):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Great job. I would recommend this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
folder_path = "C:\SampleFolder"

how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove = 7

now = time.time()

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder_path):

    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.log*'):

        if os.stat(filename).st_mtime < now - how_many_days_old_logs_to_remove * 86400: 
             os.remove(filename)
             print "\n File Removed : " , file_full_path

        # matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: Just check for the `time checking` thing during removal. Apart from that it will list you all the files having `.log*` in it.

Answer (score 0):

We could use **Regular expressions** to determine if the file is a `log` file.

Rather than using `time` module you could use `datetime` module if your sole intention is to delete the log files that are older than 7 days.
Have a look at code below:

```
import re
import datetime
import os

folder_path = "C:\SampleFolder"
only_files = []

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_full_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(file_full_path) and re.search(r".*\.log.*", file_full_path):
        # Delete files older than x days
        last_mod_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(file_full_path).st_mtime)
        limt_mod_time = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

        if last_mod_time < limt_mod_time:
            os.remove(file_full_path)
            print("\n File Removed : ", file_full_path)
```